# Web scraping code using BS4+request not refreshing

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I have a problem with a code that scrapes a weather website. It's supposed to update hourly, but for some reason, the data given is not the current data on the website; it also doesn't update its data, but keeps feeding the same data continuously. Please help!!!

Also, I need help scraping the weather icon from the site.

Here is my code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from plyer import notification
import requests
import time

if __name__ == '__main__':

    while True:
        def notifyMe(title, message):
            notification.notify(
                title = title,
                message = message,
                #app_icon = icon,
                timeout = 7
            )

        try:
            # site = requests.get('https://weather.com/weather/today/l/5.02,7.97?par=google')
            site = requests.get('https://weather.com/en-NG/weather/today/l/4dce0117809bca3e9ecdaa65fb45961a9718d6829adeb72b6a670240e10bd8c9')
            # site = requests.get('http://localhost/weather.com/weather/today/l/5.02,7.97.html')
            soup = BeautifulSoup(site.content, 'html.parser')
            day = soup.find(class_= 'CurrentConditions--CurrentConditions--14ztG')

            location = day.find(class_='CurrentConditions--location--2_osB').get_text()
            timestamp = day.find(class_='CurrentConditions--timestamp--3_-CV').get_text()
            tempValue = day.find(class_='CurrentConditions--tempValue--1RYJJ').get_text()
            phraseValue = day.find(class_='CurrentConditions--phraseValue--17s79').get_text()
            precipValue = day.find(class_='CurrentConditions--precipValue--1RgXi').get_text()
            #icon = day.find(id ='svg-symbol-cloud').get_icon()

            weather = timestamp + "\n" + tempValue + " " + phraseValue + "\n" + precipValue
        except requests.exceptions.ConnectionError:
            location = "Couldn't get a location."
            weather = "Error connecting to website."
        except AttributeError:
            weather = timestamp + "\n" + tempValue + " " + phraseValue
   
        # print (weather)

        notifyMe( location, weather )
        time.sleep(30)
```

Expected output:

Uyo, Akwa Ibom Weather
As of 13:28 WAT
30° Mostly Cloudy
55% chance of rain until 14:00

Comment: what's your expected output. please [edit] your question and include it.

Comment: first you could print errors in `except` to see if you get new data - `except AttributeError as ex: print(ex)`. If you have `AttributeError` then it uses the same values - and you see the same values. And you don't even know that you get error because you don't display it.

Comment: you could create `notifyMe` before `while`-loop. You don't have to create it again and again.

Comment: `weather.com` may uses JavaScript to add element adn `beautifulsoup` can't run JavaScript and you may need to use [Selenium](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/) to control real web browser which can run JavaScript

Comment: server may have some system to detect scripts/bots/spamers/hackers and send different HTML then you expect. It may also change classes - use other random numbers in classes - to make scraping harder.

Comment: @furas actually he can just `try/except` --> `AttributeError` after checking for `response` code. and regarding the logo, IDK what he want to get actually, as he can construct the `SVG` itself after getting it's values from the `HTML`. btw i posted an answer for him

Comment: (1) Expected output uploaded. (2) I originally had the `notifyMe` outside the loop, but brought it in in an attempt to correct the refresh issues. (3) I'll try the `AttributeError` again as you suggested. (4) If it all doesn't work, I'll have to delve into selenium.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


def main(url):
    r = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'lxml')

    x = list(soup.select_one('.card').stripped_strings)
    del x[4:8]
    print(x)


main('https://weather.com/en-NG/weather/today/l/4dce0117809bca3e9ecdaa65fb45961a9718d6829adeb72b6a670240e10bd8c9')
```

Output:

```
['Uyo, Akwa Ibom Weather', 'As of 8:03 WAT', '24°', 'Cloudy', '47% chance of rain until 9:00']
```

Comment: Nice idea, but it's still having the refresh issue. The output still stays the same.

Comment: @Ubong which output you expecting it to be changed?

Comment: Actually, it works. It turns out that it takes a while before the data is uploaded and my refresh time was too short, so the new

Comment: @Ubong then you can construct the `svg` as i mentioned before within comments.

Answer (score 0):

It appears the error might have been from the site, because it's working now without the issues. Thank you all for the suggestions. @Ahmed American your code is beautiful. I've learnt from it. @furas I'll try to construct the SVG as you suggested.

[That's the output.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BXfmp.png)